# Messenger keeps removing itself from list of distracting apps

Tags: facebook-messenger, digital-wellbeing

I use Digital Wellbeing's focus mode frequently and set up a list of distracting apps that includes Facebook Messenger. However, regularly, while focus mode is enabled, I get Messenger chat notifications and when I check the list of distracting apps, Messenger is no longer there.
Is there a way to force it to remain in the list?